# Where to put source files for a Sinatra app mounted within a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I have a standalone Sinatra app with its complete directory structure, and I have a Rails app with its own directory structure. I want to mount the Sinatra app within my Rails app by adding a `mount` statement in my routes file.

Where should I put the source files for my Sinatra app within my Rails directory structure to follow "best practices"? Ideally, I would want to preserve the directory structure for my Sinatra app and all its layouts, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer to have it as its own gem with a dependency from the Rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no specific place. I'd put it in `/lib`. You can also place it in its own folder in `/app`, but `/app` has special reloading and autoloading rules.

You can place it in `/lib`, require the Sinatra app and mount it in the `routes.rb` file.